# Why am I getting the error "bad operand types for binary operator" in my methods?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, operators, operands

```
public class t<T extends Number>{

private ArrayList<T> a = new ArrayList<T>();

public void add(T x){

  a.add(x);
}

public T largest(){

  T large = a.get(0);
  int count = 1;

  while(a.get(count)!=null){

     if(a.get(count)>large)
        large = a.get(count);
     count++;
  }
  return large;
}

public T smallest(){

  T small = a.get(0);
  int count = 1;

  while(a.get(count)!=null){

     if(a.get(count)<small)
        small = a.get(count);
     count++;
  }
  return small;
}
```

}

I am receiving the error in my *if* statements within my *largest* and *smallest* methods. I've had no luck in troubleshooting the error. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`a.get(int)` isn't convertible to a primitive numeric type (it's `Number`, in general, which can't be auto-unboxed), so you can't use `<` or `>`.

You will need to provide an explicit `Comparator<T>` (or, more generally, `Comparator<? super T>`), to allow you to compare elements of the list:

```
public class t<T extends Number>{
  private Comparator<? super T> comparator;

  t(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
  }

  public T largest(){
    // ...
    if (comparator.compare(a.get(count), large) > 0) {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```